# How to find alternating sum of powers

Tags: sequences-and-series

I saw a problem on this concept in a programming contest.But I never solved or saw these series before.

How to find the sum of these series up to n terms?

$$1 - 2 + 3 - 4 + ..... +(-1)^{n+1} \times  (n)$$

$$1 - 4 + 9 - 16 + ..... +(-1)^{n+1} \times  (n)^{2}$$

$$1 - 8 + 27 - 64 + ..... +(-1)^{n+1} \times  (n)^{3}$$

For the first series , I can find the sum by writing it as difference of two series,

$$1+3+5+..... - (2+4+6+..........)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extend what you did for the first sequence to the others as follows:

For the first one:

$$ \sum_{i=1}^{\frac{n}{2}} (2i-1) - \sum_{i=1}^{\frac{n}{2}} 2i $$

For the second one:

$$ \sum_{i=1}^{\frac{n}{2}} (2i-1)^2 - \sum_{i=1}^{\frac{n}{2}} (2i)^2 $$

For the third one:

$$ \sum_{i=1}^{\frac{n}{2}} (2i-1)^3 - \sum_{i=1}^{\frac{n}{2}}(2i)^3 $$

**Note: I've assumed n to be even, in taking the upper limits. If n is odd, the upper limit of the first summation will be $\frac{n+1}{2}$ and that of the second will be $\frac{n-1}{2}$**

I've written the summations separately to make what I've done clear. In case of $n$ being even, you can club the two summations and cancel out the highest degree term.

All that's left to do is apply the following formulas:

$$ \sum_{i=1}^{k} i=\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$$
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{k} i^2=\frac{k(k+1)(2k+1)}{6}$$
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{k} i^3=\frac{k^2(k+1)^2}{4}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @ZAN No problem. Glad to help.